# How to connect old .dll to project on C# VS2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have some problem with one .dll file. I can't connect it to my project. When I try to do it I have message that "One or more errors occured. The reference is invalid or unsupported". File isn't corrupted, but VS can't open it. So I [added Assembly to the cache](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28126/unable-to-add-reference-in-visual-studio-2017-refe.html). It didn't solve my problem.
About .dll: Thats .dll file was written in 2005 on CLI. You can download that .dll [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGOGp0iZJ9uac4Le6euPA2aw5xS1S9Nw/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Old dlls before WinXP cannot be directly used by a managed project.  You need to create a c++ wrapper to access the dll.

Comment: I gusess your dll project is written by VS2003 or VS2005, You'd better write a simple dll loader(exe) with VS2003 or 2005, to make sure you dll is loadable in your current enviroment.